# backlit keyboard turns ON after shutdown or in sleep in MacBook Air M1

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, shutdown, apple-silicon

My 10 days old MacBook Air M1 laptop is behaving abnormally i.e it's Keyboard Backlit light turns ON after I Shutdown my laptop or put it on sleep. The light starts flashing or becomes still. And when I turn MacBook On it becomes normal just like before.
Currently it is running on BigSur 11.5.2
I have also went to system preferences.
I have tried Diagnostics test but no issue was found.

Answer (score 0):

It may be an electronic malfunction and probably nothing you can fix yourself. I'd call Apple and ask them what you should do. I'm sure they will either fix it or send you a new one.

Comment: The problem is, the kind of service the company provides in INDIA, is worst, hectic and also regretful . The seller is not providing a new one, they say get it repaired for a brand new 5 days old laptop.... Worst service... It is a shame for the Company like this.

Comment: OK, yeah, I have no idea how Apple operates overseas. It could be a totally different experience for you.

Comment: You mention being in India. Without getting political, you may want to invest in a surge protector, just for your most expensive gadgets. They even have surge protector extension cords available I think.

 Otherwise, have you tried an SMC reset? See here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

Answer (score 0):

Do you live in a very humid area? or had any water spill on your keyboard? I also have the exact same issue on my few weeks old M1 MacBook Air and I was suspecting humidity to be the cause! Anyway, I guess the Service Center will be able to give a better diagnosis in both of our cases.

Comment: No I don't live in a humid area. And no water spill had happened for sure.